# "Attribute selected true" of the localStorage Item value

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I have a selectbox and I'm trying to set the value of **localStorage.getItem("Selectoption")**, the default select option.

I tried (but doesn't work):

`$("#Selectbox").val(localStorage.getItem("Selectoption")).attr('selected', true);`

Although this works:

`$("#Selectbox").val("Option1").attr('selected', true);`

Does anyone know how can I set **.attr('selected', true);** of **localStorage.getItem("Selectoption") value**. ??

Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `selected` attribute on `select` element and not the option. Try this

```
var optionValue = localStorage.getItem("Selectoption");
$("#Selectbox").val(optionValue)
.find("option[value=" + optionValue +"]").attr('selected', true);
```

On a side note, just setting the `value` of the `select` element is enough you don't have to explicitly set the `selected` attribute.

Comment: ShankarSangoli, once again you've helped me wisely. Thanks alot sir

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to run `attr('selected', true)`. It doesn't make any sense to run this on the `<select>` element, and setting the `val()` of the `<select>` box already makes the `<option>` with that value selected.

Answer (score 0):

$("#" + listbox).find("option:selected").attr('Selected',true);